# Узнать заряд батареи на Android

Tags: android, qt5, qt, c++

Задача очень распространенная, но не могу найти реализации на QT 5.x.

Надо узнать текущий уровень заряда батареи смартфона/планшета на Android.

Comment: @helpforprogrammer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7):

Вот обычный java метод, может, поможет:

```
public float getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new     IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    if(level == -1 || scale == -1) {
        return 50.0f;
    }

    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. На Java работает. Теперь пытаюсь подключить этот метод в QT через JNI. Если знаете, как соединить их, подскажите.

Comment: Как использовать этот код в QT5 JNI?

Я получаю ошибку: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()